# Adapting single file uploader to become multifile uploader

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

So I have been working today on getting a drag and drop file upload script working which for a single file it does. I have now come to try and make it allow multiple files but am running in to an issue.

```
// Required for drag and drop file access
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

// Set the dropzone
$("#dropzone-wrapper").on('drop', function(event) {
// Do something with the file(s)
var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

if (files.type.match('image.*')) {
    // If the file is an image, then run the processFileUpload function
    processFileUpload(files);
} else {
    alert("Not an image!");
}
});

// Process the file that was dropped
function processFileUpload(droppedFile) {

var uploadFormData = new FormData(); 
uploadFormData.append("image",droppedFile);

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');

$.ajax({
    url : "Uploader/upload.php", // use your target
    type : "POST",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.progress').show();
        var percentVal = 0;
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal + '%');

        window.setInterval(function(){
            var x = (100 / (droppedFile.size / 100000));
            var x = Math.round(x);

            if (x >= 90) { clearInterval(); } else {
            percentVal = percentVal + x;
            percent.html(percentVal + '%');
            bar.width(percentVal + '%'); }
        }, 1000);

    },
    complete: function() {
        clearInterval();
        bar.width("100%");
        percent.html("100%");
    },
    data : uploadFormData,
    chache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) { 

        window.location = data;

    }
   });
}
```

The error I'm getting is **Cannot call method 'match' of undefined ** which relates to line 9. Now my guess is that it is having an issue checking multiple files because as I say, it is fine checking just the one. How do I go about making it check if all the files being uploaded are images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add each file individually, `files` is a list of files, also you'll have to change `processFileUpload` to handle multiple files

```
var filesToUpload = [];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    if (files[i].type.match('image.*')) {
        filesToUpload.push(files[i]);
    } else {
        alert("Not an image!");
    }
}
processFileUpload(filesToUpload);

...

function processFileUpload(droppedFiles) {
...
var uploadFormData = new FormData(); 
for (var i = 0; i < droppedFiles.length; i++){
    uploadFormData.append("image[]",droppedFiles[i]);
}
...
```

Comment: The only problem with doing this now... it's not sending all the images at once to my upload.php so I can't treat them as an array. It sends each file individually. Is this what's supposed to happen?

Comment: @Tenatious I assumed it would send them as an array, I'll test it out and get back to you.

Comment: @Tenatious I get it as an array in php, what are you using on your server side?

Comment: PHP. Hmm. Cause when I used the foreach in my PHP page its throwing up errors which I can only assume are relating to it not coming through as an array?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I didn't realise you'd made another edit. It's sending it as an array now.